# How do I store a matrix inside a row of another matrix in C++?

Tags: c++, matrix

My code is the following:

```
#define ROWS    3
#define COLUMNS 3

int main()
{
    int fields[COLUMNS][ROWS];
    int **sudoku[COLUMNS][ROWS];
    sudoku[0][0] = fields;

    return 0;
}
```

I want to store **fields** inside **sudoku**, whats the right syntax for that?
*How do I store a matrix inside a row of another matrix?*

Comment: `int **` is an array of pointers, not a 2-D array.

Comment: Use `std::vector` and smart pointers, instead of arrays and pointers.

Comment: In fact, `sudoku` is an array of arrays of pointers to pointers to int.  It think that is actually *more* complex than `int ****` (a pointer to pointers to pointers to pointers to int).  You need a lot of typedefs in your code - and preferably some structs.

Comment: I don't actually understand the question.

Comment: @MartinBonner I think he wants a 3x3 field inside each 3x3 "sudoku field" (creates a 9x9 grid)

Comment: I think I understand your point, but some practical example would be great, I like to bump my head against to wall and learn but I prefer the probability of going the right way.
May I ask for a practical example please?

Comment: @Barmar Technically no, that's a pointer to a pointer. `int*[]` is an array of pointers.

Answer (score 3):

```
int fields[COLUMNS][ROWS];
int **sudoku[COLUMNS][ROWS];
sudoku[0][0] = (int**)fields;
```

or you can use std::array

```
using Fields = array<array<int, ROWS>, COLUMNS>;
Fields fields;
array<array<Fields, ROWS>, COLUMNS> sudoku;
sudoku[0][0] = fields; // this will copy the data
```

Comment: Plus 1 for the `std::array` solution.

Comment: thanks! would you recomend using static_cast<int**>(fields) instead of C cast?

Comment: The version with the cast allows the assignment, but you still won't be able to access the array elements using that pointer, because it expects `sudoku[0][0]` to be a pointer to a pointer, not a pointer to an array.

Comment: @BrianFiszman yes, but listen to that Barmar has just said. And if you allowed to use std::array, that could be the thing you want.

Comment: so the only good way of doing this (readable way I may add to this point) is by using smart pointers and std::array

Comment: @BrianFiszman It depends how you would like to use. Smart pointers will bring some additional overhead, and you data will be not so cache friendly. std::array resides on the stack.

Comment: @Yola still you recommend std::array?

Comment: @BrianFiszman For data of a size like 3by3 definitely yes. And hardly your data will too big, haven't seen to big sudok;) So, std::array is the choice here.